# Partition By Logic in Code to calculate value of a DataTable Column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I'm using the following SQL for calculating the value of a column named `weight` within a view.
I need to move this calculation logic to code.

```
CASE
WHEN SUM(BaseVal) OVER (PARTITION BY TEMPS.MandateCode) = 0 THEN 0
ELSE (BaseVal / (SUM(BaseVal) OVER (PARTITION BY TEMPS.MandateCode))) END AS [Weight]
```

Is iterating over each and grouping by `MandateCode`  a good idea

```
 var datatableenum = datatable.AsEnumerable();
            foreach(var item in datatableenum)
            {
  List<DataTable> result = datatable.AsEnumerable()
             .GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("MandateCode"))
             .Select(g => g.CopyToDataTable())
             .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to say "no" because as you have it, it will perform the group operation for every mandate code, for each row then copy then to list, which adds up to a huge amount of burnt resources.. I would make a dictionary of mandatecode=>sum first and then use it when iterating the table

```
var d = datatable.AsEnumerable()
  .GroupBy(
    row => row.Field<int>("MandateCode"),
    row => row.Field<double>("BaseVal")
  ).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum());
```

Note I've no idea what type BaseVal is; you need to adjust this. If it's an integer remember that you'll be doing a calc  of `small_int/big_int` eg `12/6152`, which is always 0 so cast one of the operandi to eg double so the result will be like 0.1234

Then use the dictionary on each row

```
foreach(var item in datatableenum)
{
    int sumbv = d[item.Field<int>("MandateCode"));
    item["Weight"] = sumbv == 0 ? 0 : item.Field<double>("BaseVal") / sumbv; 
}
```